# Positioning Nodes At Below the Bottom of the Screen (Spritekit)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Hello I'm trying to spawn bullets at the bottom of my screen to travel upwards but the current code that I have spawns the bullets at the top of the screen. I've tried making the height negative and nothing happened. Here's the code I'm working with, thanks.

```
let randomBulletPosition = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: -300, highestValue: 300)
    let position = CGFloat(randomBulletPosition.nextInt())
    bullet.position = CGPoint(x: position, y: self.frame.size.height + bullet.size.height)
```

Comment: It greatly depends on container node what you are going to see . When a node is added to a parent, it is positioned using the parent's coordinate system. Also positioning depends on parent's anchor point. So, show us the parent node (print its anchor point, its position and its size). If a  parent node is a scene, position property is irrelevant, but you could tell us instead about the view size, and `scene.scaleMode` (along with other data I mentioned above)..

Comment: Generally, if your scene's (as well as node's) anchor point is 0.5, 0.5 which is default, a node with position set to  `CGPoint.zero` will be placed in the center of the screen. So, to put a node right *behind* the top edge (so it isn't visible),  you should do this: `node.position = frame.size.height / 2 + node.frame.size.height/2`

Comment: @Whirlwind, thanks for the response, I honestly do not understand what you mean by the parent node (very new to this), and I tried the code you gave above and it gave me an error saying, "No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'CGPoint'

Comment: Parent node is a node that your node is added to as a child. If that make sense to you. When you do `nodeA.addChild(nodeB)`, nodeA is set as a parent node for `nodeB`. So if you examine `nodeB.parent`, you will see what I am talking about. Also, node can have only one parent. If you try to add a node to another parent you will get error.

Comment: Yeah, the error you are getting is because I made a mistake. You should use `node.position.y`, rather than `node.position`...node.position is `CGPoint`. A typo...

Comment: @Whirlwind, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some nice conversions will help you.

Now, do not do this all the time,  this should be a one and done type deal,  like in a `lazy` property.

First, we want to get the bottom of our view

```
let viewBottom = CGPoint(x:scene!.view!.midX,y:scene!.view!.frame.maxY)  //In a UIView, 0,0 is the top left corner, so we look to bottom middle
```

Second, we want to convert the position to the scene

```
let sceneBottom = scene!.view!.convert(viewBottom, to:scene!)
```

Finally we want to convert to whatever node you need it to be a part of.  (This is optional if you want to place it on the scene)

```
let nodeBottom = scene!.convert(sceneBottom,to:node)
```

Code should look like this:

```
let viewBottom = CGPoint(x:scene!.view!.midX,y:scene!.view!.frame.maxY)  
let sceneBottom = scene!.view!.convert(viewBottom!, to:scene!)
let nodeBottom = scene!.convert(sceneBottom,to:node)
```

Of course, this is a little ugly.

Thankfully we have convertPoint and convert(_from:) to clean things up a little bit

```
let sceneBottom = scene.convertPoint(from:viewBottom)
```

Which means we can clean up the code to look like this:

```
let sceneBottom = scene.convertPoint(from:CGPoint(x:scene!.view!.midX,y:scene!.view!.frame.maxY))
let nodeBottom = node.convert(sceneBottom,from:scene!)
```

Then we can make it 1 line as:

```
let nodeBottom = node.convert(scene.convertPoint(from:CGPoint(x:scene!.view!.midX,y:scene!.view!.frame.maxY),from:scene!)
```

As long as the node is available to the class, we can make it lazy:

```
lazy var nodeBottom = self.node.convert(self.scene!.convertPoint(CGPoint(x:self.scene!.view!.midX,y:self.scene!.view!.frame.maxY),from:self.scene!)
```

This means the first time you call nodeBottom, it will do these calculations for you and store it into memory.  Everytime after that, the number is preserved.

Now that you know where the bottom of the screen is in the coordinate system you want to use, you can assign the x value to whatever your random is producing, and you can subtract the (node.height * (1 - node.anchorPoint.y)) to fully hide your node from the scene.

Now keep in mind, if your node moves between various parents, this lazy will not update.

Also note,  I unwrapped all optionals with !,  you may want to be using ? and checking if it exists first.

Comment: thanks for the response, I got an error saying that "cannot invoke 'convert' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat, to:SKScene?)'"

Comment: could you tell me on which line?

Comment: The   "let sceneBottom = scene!.view!.convert(viewBottom, to:scene)" line

Comment: no problem,  this conversion will work on any anchor points and through any nodes with children, so there is no need to have to worry about anchors or parents.  It even helps with scene cropping for when you use aspect fill